# Change id visibility via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my html

```
<select name="change" id="games">
<option value="game1">Tennis Championship</option>
<option value="game2">The Champions 3D</option>
<option value="game3">Pool Championship</option>
</select>

<div id="game1" style="display:none">...
```

My script

```
$("#games").change(function(){
$("#game1").show();});
```

This is not working :( Why?

Comment: id games might be repeated or game1 id is repeated.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what "working" would mean, and what it does instead?

Comment: seems to be behaving exactly as I would expect: http://jsfiddle.net/u3f8nksL/  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Is your script wrapped in a `$(document).ready(){ }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#games").change(function(){
        $("#game1").show();
        //or get an alert to see is the select working well or not:
        alert($("select#games").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: and did you call jquery in another script tag?

Answer (score 0):

your code works you will and you can also decrease your code

```js
$("#games").change(function () {
    var a = $(this).val();
    $("div[id^='game']").hide();
    $('#' + a).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="change" id="games">
    <option value="game1">Tennis Championship</option>
    <option value="game2">The Champions 3D</option>
    <option value="game3">Pool Championship</option>
</select>
<div id="game1" style="display:none">game1</div>
<div id="game2" style="display:none">game2</div>
<div id="game3" style="display:none">game3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,great help my friend :)

Comment: your welcome @fafasfa :) do accept my answer if it has helped you